# What do I call a word with roots from multiple languages?

Tags: etymology, single-word-requests, roots

As best as I can tell, a good example is *sociopath*:

> [sociopath](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sociopath) — from *socio-* on model of *psychopath*
>
> [socio-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=socio-) — combining form of [Latin] *socius*
>
> [pathos](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pathos) — from [Greek] pathos

Hence, *sociopath* is a word coined from roots found in two different languages. Is there a good term that describes this?

Comment: The most common example is "television". The inventor, John Baird, coined the name by combining the Greek "tele"(distant), with the Latin "vision"(seeing).

Comment: [linsey-woolsey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linsey-woolsey) from [A Word A Day](http://wordsmith.org/words/linsey-woolsey.html)

Comment: Another amusing example: http://www.joeydevilla.com/2011/06/01/why-polyamory-is-wrong/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I came across the term ["hybrid word"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word) when I was researching *quadraphonic* (which is one).  This phrase would work for your situation.

Plus, "sociopath" is listed as an example of a hybrid word in the linked page.

Comment: Although accurate, this term is not particularly useful, since it relies on context to clarify its meaning.

Comment: @Urbycoz What other meanings would "hybrid word" have?  I can't think of any.

Comment: @Kit I'm not saying it doesn't make sense. It just doesn't seem to be immediately obvious what it would mean.

Comment: @Urbycoz You mean it's not really common usage, not that it means different things? I guess I agree with that.

Comment: @Kit, I like the article, but one of the issues with it is that it lists a single source http://www.zuckermann.org/pdf/Hybridity_versus_Revivability.pdf ; in which the term "hybrid word" is actually not mentioned (I could not find it).

Comment: +1 *Hybrid* is frequently used to describe words with mixed backgrounds. It is as far as I know the only current word. Look no further.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know that there is an accepted single term for words of this sort. I suggest that we coin the self-describing term ***heteroradical***.

Comment: +1 for a bold proposition. But does that make the rest of our words *homoradical*? Just curious.

Comment: I reject this new term on the grounds that it is too-clever-by-half.

Comment: @Robusto, naturally words from a single source are *homoradical*, or if you prefer, *unirhizoid*.

Comment: Maybe heterolingual compound is better? Polylingual?

Comment: I would +1 you for the pun, but I must confine my support to Kit for *hybrid*.

Answer (score 1):

'**Multilingually derived**' though two separate words, avoids neologisms and says what it means.

Comment: That's ambiguous; it could refer to a word that has been borrowed under the influence of multiple languages. Consider the several English words influenced by both Spanish and Portuguese.

Comment: @Mechanical snail: can you give some examples? A couple which are so influenced and explain how?

Comment: A class of examples are from artificial languages like Esperanto, where morphemes are often intentionally chosen to be cognate to words in many languages. Examples in English: the morpheme [*-ado*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ado), from Spanish and Portuguese; *incommunicado*, word from Spanish but spelling from English (ultimately from Latin).

Comment: @Mechanical snail: oh, that sounds exactly like what the OP is talking about, any kind of word with roots or influences from distinct parent languages. Anyway, 'hybrid' is a succinct word for the situation (i.e. it's better than mine).

Comment: I think he was talking about words containing one morpheme from one language and another morpheme from another.

Comment: @Mechanical snail: I think pedantically speaking both 'incommunic-' and '-ado' are considered morphemes.

Comment: The etymology is the complete word *incomunicado* from Spanish, whose spelling was fused with the English morpheme *communic*.

Comment: @Mechanical snail: OK then. but then I really don't understand your objection in your first comment. Are you saying my suggestion is ambiguous? The OPs desire, and your example fit under it just fine; if that is an ambiguity, I still think it works (just not as good as 'hybrid').